# the body message sent to client's email has %20 instead of spaces

Tags: javascript, email

The link to the ide I code in from sololearn.com is https://code.sololearn.com/Wg70wiK3e0h3/#html but there I can never actually send the email, so then I use the notepad and the body message that is sent is filled by %20 as if it was a link. The "code" below is the function in which I build the body message and send the email. If you go to my full code in sololearn it is in line 2000ish and its called in line 3000ish. By the way the rest of the code is working perfectly fine.

This function has more to it but it's too big to put it here but basically I add the data to the message variable, just like the gender one but multiple times with multiple variables, but all with the same syntax. I tried using decodeURI but then it does not work once it's a link. Is there another way to send the email, a way in which the body message isn't all screwed up?

```
function sendEmail() {

    message = "Hi this is just a way for you to have all the main data summed up saved in your email inbox. \n \n";

    message += "Gender: ";

    message += genderreturn;

    message += " \n";

    url = "mailto:" + emailaddrreturn + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + message;

    location.href = url; //(might want to use window.location or something else here)
```

}

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `message.replace(/%20/g, " ");`

Comment: I mean, if I use it and it actually replaces this %20, then the window to send the email does not load, because I am sending it through a link. I think this is the problem: through Javascript, I don't know any other way to send an email. Do you know any other?

Comment: oh i see. you can try decodeURIComponent(message) to decode the url,, it'll remove %20 and your url will still be valid

refrence: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp